# Execute SQL query using Groovy script

Tags: sql, groovy, soapui

I am trying to run SQL update query using Groovy script.

```
//Global Properties Value
def dbServer = context.expand('${#Project#DB_Server}')
def dbPort = context.expand('${#Project#DB_Port}')
def dbName = context.expand('${#Project#DB_Name}')
def dbUser = context.expand('${#Project#DB_Username}')
def dbPass = context.expand('${#Project#DB_Password}')
def userID = context.expand('${#Project#userID}').toInteger()

//Convert HEX to Integer
def userSerialHex = context.expand('${#Project#userSerial}').toString();
BigInteger userSerialInteger = Long.parseLong(userSerialHex, 16);

log.info userSerialHex
log.info userID
log.info userSerialInteger

//Connection String
def con = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:sqlserver://$dbServer:$dbPort;" + "databaseName=" + dbName, dbUser, dbPass, 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver')

//SQL Query
con.execute("update tblUserCardDetail set active=0 where fkUserID = $userID and cardValue = $userSerialInteger");
```

Result :

```
Fri Dec 08 20:24:25 IST 2017:INFO:182A11A53C68BD3C
Fri Dec 08 20:24:25 IST 2017:INFO:12901
Fri Dec 08 20:24:25 IST 2017:INFO:1741223607312891196
```

Expected : It should return true and update the row.

Error i am getting :

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The conversion from UNKNOWN to UNKNOWN is unsupported. error at line: 27

When i run the query from sql server then it updated successfully.

```
update tblUserCardDetail set active=0 where fkUserID=12901 and cardValue=1741223607312891196
```

Comment: can you check the solution to see if that helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow it works when i changed the SQL connection in other way, this time i parameter the whole connection including jdbc driver :

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
def dbString = context.expand('${#Project#DB_String}')
def dbDriver = context.expand('${#Project#DB_Driver}')
def dbUser = context.expand('${#Project#DB_Username}')
def dbPass = context.expand('${#Project#DB_Password}')
def con = Sql.newInstance(dbString, dbUser, dbPass, dbDriver)

//SQL Query
con.execute("update tblUserCardDetail set active=0 where fkUserID = $userID and cardValue = '$userSerialInteger'");
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to convert BigInteger `userSerialInteger` to String explicitly.

Something like:

`con.execute("update tblUserCardDetail set active=0 where fkUserID = $userID and cardValue = ${userSerialInteger.toString()}");`

From the source code of `groovy.sql.Sql#execute(groovy.lang.GString)`

```
    List<Object> params = getParameters(gstring);
    String sql = asSql(gstring, params);
    return execute(sql, params);
```

The params of gstring is passed to execute without processing.

Comment: Now the message displayed :
Script-result: false

Comment: I don't understand, can you provide more details? The full message?

Comment: This is the only message i received. I think query run successfully but somehow it return false and does not updating record in DB.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things to note while using sql connection using `Groovy Script` in SoapUI.

1. Copy the driver library under `SOAPUI_HOME/bin/ext` directory and restart the tool.
2. Register the driver first with the driver class name. For instance, `mysql` server

   com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils.registerJdbcDriver( "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" )
3. Now use your connection and execute the queries.

Coming to your question, you can use [jTDC](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/files/jtds/1.3.1/jtds-1.3.1-dist.zip) driver and copy the jar file to the mentioned location.

Script to get the connection:

```
def DRIVER_CLASS='net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver'
def CONNECTION_STRING="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://${databaseServer}:${databasePort}/${databaseName};domain=${domain}" as String
com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils.registerJdbcDriver(DRIVER_CLASS)
def sql = Sql.newInstance(CONNECTION_STRING, DRIVER_CLASS)
```

Now you should be able to execute the query using `sql.execute(..)`.

Note that the above connection string is using place holder values, just use the right variables or use actual values.

Comment: My other sql queries working fine with existing JDBC driver. 
e.g : def res = con.firstRow("select * from tblusercarddetail where fkuserID=$userID and cardValue='$userSerialInteger' and active=1" )
Should i still try this jTDC? Does this con.execute requires jTDC?

Answer (score 0):

This type of error comes from the SQL driver trying to tell you it doesn't know how to convert the values you're passing as arguments.

You can either try changing your `def userID` to `int userID` or casting your parameter as below.

Even if `groovy.sql` is smart enough to change it, I'd also advise in favor of using a method with parameters for your update statement (e.g. [`groovy.sql.Sql.executeUpdate(String, List)`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#executeUpdate-java.lang.String-java.util.List-)):

```
con.executeUpdate('update tblUserCardDetail set active=0 where fkUserID = ? and cardValue = ?', [userID.toInteger(), userSerialInteger])
```

Edit: As noted by @aristotll, the `execute(GString)` is not that smart. Which reinforces my advice above, since converting to text is not a very good practice. However, you also need to make sure you are using the correct types on both sides, as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-basic-data-types) if you're using the Microsoft JDBC driver.

Comment: Now the error occurred --> 
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The conversion from UNKNOWN to UNKNOWN is unsupported. error at line: 27